# If I buy a movie on YouTube, will it also be in my Google Play library?

Tags: youtube, google-play-store

If I buy a movie on YouTube, will I also own it on the Google Play Store?

For instance, if I were to buy [Tomorrowland on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wdp2exiD3U), would I have it in my [Google Play library](https://play.google.com/store/movies/details?id=_wdp2exiD3U)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, movies purchased on YouTube will be in your Google Play Library and vice versa.**

According to [Android Authority](http://www.androidauthority.com/youtube-app-streams-play-movies-399478/), video purchases from the Google Play Store have been integrated with YouTube since 2014.

> [...] Google has just updated its back end to integrate your Google Play
>   movie and TV purchases into the Youtube app, bringing the service in
>   line with the desktop feature.
>
> You will now be able to find all of your movie and TV purchases under
>   the new Purchases section in the Youtube menu, right under the Watch
>   Later option.

While Android Authority doesn't specifically say whether ***YouTube*** purchases are synced to Google Play, an old [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/4bzrqy/buying_movies_on_google_play_vs_youtube/) confirms that yes, movie purchases are shared between YouTube and Google Play.

---

#### Sources

- [Android Authority - Youtube app now streams Google Play Movies and TV shows](http://www.androidauthority.com/youtube-app-streams-play-movies-399478/)
- [Reddit - Buying movies on Google Play vs YouTube](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/4bzrqy/buying_movies_on_google_play_vs_youtube/)
- [Reddit - TIL I can watch my Google Play Movies library through the YouTube app](https://www.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/2lnaf2/til_i_can_watch_my_google_play_movies_library/)
- [Reddit - Play your Google Play Movies/TV purchases through YouTube, not the Google Play website](https://www.reddit.com/r/google/comments/3xq81o/psa_play_your_google_play_moviestv_purchases/)

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that movies bought on youtube then appear in Google Play, the two are not entirely interchangeable. Specifically, a movie bought via youtube is not viable to be added to your Google Play Family Library, should you have such a thing set up.

Sources:

- [Use google play family library](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7007852?hl=en-GB) - check the 'See if content is eligible to be added to family library' section.
- A [Google help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/play/5gWxFaT4IgM/R9IIQ2I5CQAJ) full of people asking for help and getting little response.
- My own, woefully sparse, family library...

Comment: So is it better to purchase on Google Play Movies?

Comment: I think so. I'm not aware of any benefit to buying it on youtube instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Support, yes. As long as both accounts are under the same email.

"If you purchase a movie on Google Play, you can watch it on YouTube and vice versa"

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you found this information?

Comment: Just the question I was going to ask @AlE.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that all of the videos in https://www.youtube.com/purchases are also listed in my [Google Play library](https://play.google.com/movies) under "My Movies" and "My TV Shows", and vice versa.

Answer (score -2):

They will appear in your Google Play Library in My Movies!

Comment: Can you provide a link for where you found this information?

Comment: This really doesn't offer any other information the other answer don't.